# Need to change the background color of datalist cell

Tags: jquery, c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5

I have a datalist with itemtemplate which contains: an anchor and an href  tag . Everytime a user clicks the link I want to change the background color to green of the  so that the whole cell looks selected. If another cell is selected then the previous background should clear up and the new cell should get the green color. Right now all the td's change to green for a second and then it cjanges to the original colors. The issue is that I cannot get unique id because of the DataList control. There is a unique table name and but all the td are identical. So there are 2 issues.

- To have the background color remain
  until the user clicks another cell
- Have a unique id to recognize which
  cell was selected by the click event.

How can I do that? Please help.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DL1" ItemStyle-Width="50%"  runat="server" DataSourceID="ds1" 
        RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table">  
     <ItemTemplate>
          <a onclick="testl('<%= DL1.ClientID %>')" 
               href='<%# "Color.aspx?id=" + Eval("id") %>'> 
                       Click to change background
          </a> 
      </ItemTemplate>
 </datalist>
```

---

```
    function test(id) {
        $("#" + id + " td").css({ 'background-color': 'green' });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it is changing back to the original colors is, I think due to the fact that the link is being taken.  Should that be handled via AJAX, or simply ignored?  I'll assume that you can use the href to load up some html that will display in a DIV named *displayArea*. Also, I'd consider using a class instead of an id and not putting the javascript inline.  The other answer, using CSS classes is also spot on, so I'm going to change this to show changing the class to the highlight class.  Using CSS classes is a much better way to handle it.

```
<a class="changes-color" href=...>Click to change background</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('.changes-color').click( function() {

          // remove existing highlights and add highlight to this element
          $('#tableId').find('td').removeClass('highlight');
          $(this).closest('td).addClass('highlight');

          // load data into display area using ajax load
          $('#displayArea').load( $(this).attr('href') );

          // stop link from being followed
          return false;
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You are right because the link is taken and so it cannot be ignored. Can it be done with Ajax. Please advice. The link once clicked brings us back to the same page (or should I say reloads the same page)

Comment: What does the link do?  Is it updating something?  Do we need the results?

Comment: The datalist is the user choices. And once a user select (ie clicks) a link in the td the page gets reloaded with some data from the database  on the same page as per user selection. So I need to change the background of the td to show their selection with the new data info below this datalist itself.

Comment: To answer your questions:  We need the result set after the click but nothing to with this control. I just need to change the background.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by result set.  Is there another container on the page that is updated?  Can you return just that data from your method?

Comment: okay. Let me explain href='<%# "Products.aspx?id=" + Eval("id") %>'> When the user clicks on the link it takes the id from query string and displays the product info in the page below this datalist.  I hope I have interpreted your question correctly?

Comment: There is most assuredly a way to do this with AJAX but it would require you to also change your backend code.  Essentially, you wold do a load() request of a page that display only the relevant markup that needs to be displayed.  This would be loaded into the container below.  I'll put in a sample, but you'll have to write the backend code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a CSS class to identify highlightable links.

```
<a class="highlightable" href=...>Click to change background</a>
```

Then in write something like this in jQuery:

```
$(".hightlightable").click(function() { 
  $(".highlightable").removeClass("highlight");
  $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

And in your CSS:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: #008000;
}
```